# Boostrap 4 unable to change the color of navbar element?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using boostrap 4 and I want to change the color of navbar element. I have override the navbar-brand class but things are not working as expected.

[image]

I want to achieve some sort of effect as of first one. you can see white color taking of entire width and height but in second it is just appearing around the name. can you help me out. I also want this to work on my li elements

HTML

```
<head>
  <title>Samrat Luitel website design</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-expand-md topnav" role="navigation" >
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" target="_blank">Samrat Luitel</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#home" style="color:black" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#home" style="color:black" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#home" style="color:black" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>       
      </ul>   
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  </nav> 
</body>
```

CSS

```
body{
  font-family:"Lato";
  font-weight:700;
}
.topnav {
    font-size: 16px;
    border-bottom: 1px outset rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.5);
    background: rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.9);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.navbar-brand{
  color:black;
  background:white;
}
```

Comment: you can also remove the navbar class then you can easily change the color.

Comment: You should use some padding in your .navbar-brand class

Comment: @HardenRahul I dont think I will remove navbar class that causes alignment issues.

Comment: @RajanBenipuri I will try that

Comment: @SamratLuitel can u provide me the live URL or somewhere on Codepen. So that I can figure out the issue and get it solve.

Comment: Check any other style overriding default bootstrap style

Comment: @UIDeveloper please give me some idea. I am a beginner

Comment: @HardenRahul https://codepen.io/samratluintel/pen/OxKZzx?editors=1100. Here is the link. Thanks for showing interest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your CSS

```
.topnav{
  padding:0;
}
.navbar-brand {
 color: black;
 background: white;
 padding: .3125rem;
}
```

If you want to maintain your header height set min-height to topnav